# Defining accessor function for a Reference Class

Tags: r

I'm currently exploring the possibilities of R's [Reference Class](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/methods/ReferenceClasses) and I'm trying to wrap my head around customized accessor functions. The manual states for field that:

> The element in the list can alternatively be an **accessor function**, a
>   function of one argument that returns the field if called with no
>   argument or sets it to the value of the argument otherwise. Accessor
>   functions are used internally and for inter-system interface
>   applications. Their definition follows the rules for writing methods
>   for the class: they can refer to other fields and can call other
>   methods for this class or its superclasses. See the section on
>   “Implementation” for the internal mechanism used by accessor
>   functions.

All I've been able to find is using accessor functions in the context of [file storage](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2010-November/059132.html). Being accustomed to private internal variables and input validations I would argue that this is where the input data validation should be, see example below:

```
Account <- 
  setRefClass("Account",
              fields = list(data = "list",
                            balance = 
                              function(value){
                                if (missing(value)){
                                  return(data$balance)
                                }else{
                                  if (!is.numeric(value))
                                    stop("You can only set the balance to a numeric value!")
                                  data$balance <<- value
                                }
                              }),
              methods = list(
                withdraw = function(x) {
                  balance <<- balance - x
                },
                deposit = function(x) {
                  balance <<- balance + x
                }
              ))
```

This works as expected:

```
> a <- Account$new(balance = 0)
> 
> a$deposit(10)
> a$balance
[1] 10
> 
> a$withdraw(1)
> a$balance
[1] 9
> 
> a$balance <- "a"
 Error in (function (value)  : 
  You can only set the balance to a numeric value!
```

What I would like to know if there is a reason for not doing this since it seems like a natural approach but not mentioned in the manual? Is there a good way of completely hiding the data variable, e.g. using `.self <- local({data = list(); .self})` at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this as well and it appears that there is no way to fully hide the data. One thing that I noticed with your example is that you can still manually change the balance value by calling:

```
a <- Account$new(balance = 0)   
a$data$balance<-"a"
a$balance
#> [1] "a"
```

The reason it can still be manipulated is the reason I suspect it is not recommended. When the manual describes accessor functions it seems to be referring to the ones that you get if you want to use $accessor (described in the manual). Example below:

```
Account <- 
  setRefClass("Account",
              fields = list(balance = "numeric"),
              methods = list(
                withdraw = function(x) {
                  balance <<- balance - x
                },
                deposit = function(x) {
                  balance <<- balance + x
                }
              ))
Account$accessors("balance")
a<-Account$new("balance"=0)
# you can now get and set the balance with getBalance() and setBalance(x).
# (it automatically capitalizes your field name) 
a$setBalance(10)
a$getBalance()
# [10]
```

Lastly, you can always create and set the `getBalance()`/`setBalance(x)` methods manually if you want to add extra checks in the `methods` argument for `setClassRef`.
Most of this is inferred from the documentation for setClassRef. [See this link on stackoverflow below which discusses Private Members.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159317/private-members-in-r-reference-class?rq=1)

Comment: I've seen the post, I believe there is a way that within the limits of R makes variables behave in a private manner. @hadley suggests in his excellent book, Advanced R, in an [exercise](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html): *Use a field function to prevent the account balance from being directly manipulated*. He suggests using a `.balance` field and a balance field function - but it does not really hide the field. I've tried using `balance = local({balance <- NULL; my_func()...})` but that is equivalent to a [static variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable).